# Update Only TZoffset in DATETIME column

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timezone

I have a set of dates like *2023-11-30 23:59:59.0000000 +00:00*. I want to update only the time zone offset from *+00:00* to *+01:00* to all of them.
If it makes things easier, all of the times are *23:59:59.0000000* and only the date differentiates.

I've tried this:

```sql
UPDATE Table SET Date = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Date), '2023-11-30 23:59:59.0000000 +01:00')
```

But it only worked with accuracy up to seconds, without milliseconds, nanoseconds and tzoffset. I've got this error, when I tried that:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want `TODATETIMEOFFSET`:

```sql
DECLARE @YourValue datetimeoffset(7) = '2023-11-30 23:59:59.0000000 +00:00';

SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET(@YourValue,'+01:00');
```

This returns `2023-11-30 23:59:59.0000000 +01:00`. This works because it takes your `datetimeoffset` value and (implicitly) converts it to a `datetime2` first, which truncates the offset value, and then adds the new offset to the value; thus not changing the actual time and just the offset.

If you're saying that you actually change the value so that the date and time changes with the offset, then you want `SWITCHOFFSET`:

```sql
DECLARE @YourValue datetimeoffset(7) = '2023-11-30 23:59:59.0000000 +00:00';

SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(@YourValue,'+01:00');
```

This returns `2023-12-01 00:59:59.0000000 +01:00`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm a supernoob so I used `UPDATE Table SET Date = TODATETIMEOFFSET (Date, '+01:00')` but it worked anyway! :)